# Real time updating a label depending on the Date Swift

Tags: swift, date, label, nsdate, real-time

I'm trying to create an App that tells whether a shop is open or closed, and I have a "Open/Close" label inside my UI.

I would like to be able to change the content of this label depending on what time is it: I already have a function that returns - given a current time and a schedule - if the shop is open or not, but I don't know how to call it every time the time changes.

Thank you

Comment: What does your data model look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell when the date changes you can subscribe to NSCalendarDayChanged notifications. You'll get notified when the calendar date changes. (Assuming your app is running.)

If you want to detect clock changes you could set up a repeating timer that fires every second, and call your function every time it fires.

Note that that approach will only work when your app is running in the foreground. If the user switches to another app your app will get suspended pretty quickly and your timer won't fire any more.

If you only care about changes every minute on the minute, you could write code that delays until the next minute change and then creates a repeating timer that fires every minute, or every hour on the hour, or whatever interval you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update that UI every second or every interval u want, and fire the UpdateUI Event using NotificationCenter or RxSwift when it matches with your open/close time.